# Automating pg_basebackup command for recovery using cron and script

Tags: postgresql, automation, cron, postgresql-9.4

I have a 2 node system running pacemaker, corosync and postgresql 9.4. I am carrying out pgsql replication using virtual IP and am able to successfully recover a downed machine using manual commands. Now to automate stuff, I want to run the following commands in a script to get my recovered master back on cluster.

```
`#su -postgres
 $rm -rf /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/*     //To delete old data files
 $pg_basebackup -h 192.XX.XX.XX -U postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data   -X stream -P   // To recover the latest data from standby PC running latest entries
 $rm /var/lib/pgsql/tmp/PGSQL.lock
 $exit     //exit from postgresql shell
 #pcs resource cleanup msPostgresql`
```

Now when i run these commands as a script, it hangs after the first command itself i.e. su -postgres and the cursor blinks at bash$ syntax without inserting the commands down below.
I want to automate this process using cron but the script itself is not working for me. Can someone help me out here.

Regards

Comment: Do you really have "su<space>-postgres" and not "su<space>-<space>postgres"? Also - you don't really have the leading "#" and "$" do you?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know "su -postgres" is wrong. You can use either "su postgres", or "sudo -i -u postgres"

Regarding the scripts [here](https://www.itenlight.com/blog/2016/05/23/PostgreSQL+HA+with+pgpool-II+-+Part+3) you can find tested, working scripts. The one you are interested in is called "initiate_replication.sh" there.